# How compare two xpath in python

Tags: python, xpath, compare

I have two xpath strings for example:

```
/Envlope[1]/Header[1]/transactionInfo[1]/id[1]
```

and

```
/Envelope/Header/*
```

How I can compare (matching) this xpaht?
How I can make this on python or what algorithm is better use?

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope>
    <Header>
        <transactionInfo>
            <id>31234</id>
        </transactionInfo>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <message>test_31234</message>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Expected:

`/Envlope[1]/Header[1]/transactionInfo[1]/id[1]` in `/Envelope/Header/*`

`/Envlope[1]/Body[1]/message[1]` not in `/Envelope/Header/*`

`/Envlope[1]/Header[1]` not in `/Envelope/Header/*`

Comment: please be more specific about what you're trying to test. what do you mean by include? being a prefix? Matching the same elements? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need filter dictionary where keys is xpath strings. "Include" mean that /Envlope[1]/Header[1]/transactionInfo[1]/id[1] is a special case of /Envelope/Header/*.

Comment: this adds practically no information.

Comment: If think about I try matching some elements (element's paths) use only xpath. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: No, it isn't more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/):

```
import lxml.etree as ET

def is_descendant(tree,path1,path2):
    elt1=tree.xpath(path1)[0]
    elt2=tree.xpath(path2+'/descendant::*')
    return elt1 in elt2

content='''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope>
    <Header>
        <transactionInfo>
            <id>31234</id>
        </transactionInfo>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <message>test_31234</message>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
'''

tests=[
    ('/Envelope[1]/Header[1]/transactionInfo[1]/id[1]','/Envelope/Header/*'),
    ('/Envelope[1]/Body[1]/message[1]','/Envelope/Header/*'),
    ('/Envelope[1]/Header[1]','/Envelope/Header/*')    
    ]

tree=ET.fromstring(content)
for path1,path2 in tests:
    if is_descendant(tree,path1,path2):
        print('{p1} in {p2}'.format(p1=path1,p2=path2))
    else:
        print('{p1} NOT in {p2}'.format(p1=path1,p2=path2))
```

yields

```
/Envelope[1]/Header[1]/transactionInfo[1]/id[1] in /Envelope/Header/*
/Envelope[1]/Body[1]/message[1] NOT in /Envelope/Header/*
/Envelope[1]/Header[1] NOT in /Envelope/Header/*
```

PS. Note that the symbol `==` is usually reserved for a symmetric relationship: If `X == Y` then `Y == X`. In this case, you seem to be looking for an asymmetric relationship: `Y` contains `X`. So perhaps use `⊆` or somesuch symbol or phrase instead.